# Odoo 13 CE cannot preview import

Tags: docker, csv, odoo-13

I am using **Odoo 13 CE** with **Docker** when I try to import a data using csv file I got the following error:

```
Import preview failed due to: Unable to load "xls" file: requires Python module "xlrd".

For CSV files, you may need to select the correct separator.
```

I have checked the separator and everything seems ok.
[image]
I have also checked the `xlrd` library, it is installed in my container.

[image]

Please what am I missing here??